# Update multiple columns from a subquery?

Tags: sql-server-2005

How can I avoid the duplicated subquery in the following T-SQL statement:

```
update r set
  column1=(select top 1 max(column1) from region r2 where (overlapping test conditions)),
  column2=(select top 1 max(column2) from region r2 where (overlapping test conditions))
from region r
```

Basically, I have a table containing rectangle regions. For each overlapped region, I need to set some columns to the aggregation values of that overlapped region.

Thanks

EDIT: I am adding a over-simplified overlap condition here:

```
(r.left >= r2.left and r.left < r2.right) or (r.right <= r2.right and r.right > r.left)
```

The point is: both r and r2 will be referenced in the subquery. It seems like this is a perfect situation for common table expression but I cannot figure out how to use it for each record.

Comment: What would *overlapping test conditions* be, and do they correlate? Can you use a single sub query?

Comment: @astander: image a bunch of r.left > r2.left and r.top > r2.top ...; something you don't want to repeat.

Comment: Can you possibly add these where clauses in the question. If they are all the same, this will change the way we look at the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE Region
SET
  Region.Column1 = r.Column1
  Region.Column2 = r.Column2
FROM
  Region
INNER JOIN 
 (
   SELECT
        Column1,
        Column2
   FROM Region
   WHERE (your condition here)
  ) r ON r.ID = Region.ID
```

I just noticed the MAX() aggs.  Sorry didnt see that the first time.
You will have to probably have two inner joins to make that work...

so take what I have and do it for column1

```
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(Column1) FROM ... WHERE ... ) r ON r.ID = Region.ID
```

Then a second INNER JOIN

```
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(Column2) FROM ... WHERE ...)r2 ON r2.ID = Region.ID
```

And your update becomes

```
UPDATE Region
SET Region.Column1 = r1.Column1,
    Region.Column2 = r2.Column2
FROM Region
INNER JOIN
(SELECT MAX(Column1) as Column1 FROM ... WHERE ... ) r ON r.ID = Region.ID
INNER JOIN
(SELECT MAX(Column2) As Column2 FROM ... WHERE ... ) r2 ON r2.ID = Region.ID
```

Comment: @JonH: the dup subquery was what I was trying to avoid. Besides, I updated my original question to show what the where clause may look like. It seems like the condition cannot be accepted in such a subquery (The multi-part identifier "r.left" could not be bound).

Comment: Ok you hadnt mentioned that in the beginning sorry.
Let me take another look, so you want to avoid having two SELECT's to update two different fields correct?

Comment: I dont think you can due to the use of MAX on 2 different fields.  The aggregates complicates it, otherwise I would have an answer sorry.

Comment: A 'group by' on ID is missing in the last version of the query